# How can I convert varchar(6) to char(8) for a date

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

How can I convert a `varchar(6)` to `char(8)` for a datetime? For example, I need convert `022814` to `02/28/14`. In addition, since the first 'date' is defined as `varchar(6)`, 22814 is valid too. So I should be able to convert 22814 to 02/28/14.

I tried

```
select convert(char(8), '022814', 1)
```

but it returned `022814` not `02/28/14`. However

```
select convert(char(8), getdate(), 1))
```

will return right format `04/25/14`. I am not sure why?

So I think maybe I could try to convert '022814' to a datetime first. But I got an error "the conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value". Can anybody give me some idea?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! Don't store **date** related information in a string! Use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` for that purpose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to be easy, but you could do something along these lines:

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY

DECLARE @DateString VARCHAR(6)
SET @DateString = '022814'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@DateString,1,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@DateString,3,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@DateString,5,2))
```